# extending class with a static method

Tags: javascript, typescript

let's say you have a `date_ext.js` with functions:

```
Date.prototype.getMyBlaDate = function() {
  return // bla bla
};

Date.minutesBetween = function (date1, date2) {
  return // obladi-oblada
}
```

You don't want to convert entire file into typescript but you still can use the methods from it.
Let's create a definition for typescript

```
interface Date{
  getMyBlaDate():BlaBlaType;
  minutesBetween(date1:Date, date2:Date):ObladiType; 
}
```

it will work for prototyped method but not for the static one. 
How do you define static method?

Comment: Interfaces are for instance methods

Comment: well is there a way to define (describe) a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at `lib.d.ts` is appears you would use:

```
declare var Date: {
    minutesBetween(date1:Date, date2:Date):ObladiType;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like it's not currently supported; see http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/403971

Comment: is says 'the property minutesBetween does not exist' when I'm trying to use it like that

Comment: oh if I placed it within the current module and now it says 'Value of type is not newable'.. So i guess it's conflicting with the existing Date

Comment: @Agzam I see what you mean, I'm seeing the same thing.